# Proper way to install mdm display manager in ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, display-manager, mdm

I am wishing to install `mdm` display manager in ArchLinux. Normally the similar `gdm` is used, but I want to be consistent with the Cinnamon desktop I use, instead of Gnome desktop, so I'd also like to use `mdm` instead of `gdm`.

Unfortunately, `pacman` does not see `mdm`, nor `mdm-display-manager`, etc... All searches with `pacman -Ss` for similar keywords proves to be unsucessful.

The packages are available for manual download [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mdm-display-manager/), but I do not know what to do with this `.tar.gz`file. `pacman` do not let me install it with the `-U` option - basically it says it is not a package.

If I unzip it and try to use `makepkg`, then it appears to do some work, but eventually I get an error from `systemctl` saying that `mdm.service` doesn't exist.

How am I supposed to install packages which aren't automatically available through `pacman`?

Comment: Is your [AUR mdm package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mdm-display-manager/) built correctly or not?  It has several dependencies that must be fulfilled, the linked page provides the dependency list.  There are some AUR packages in the dependency list but they do appear in the PKGBUILD file, therefore they're optional dependencies.

Comment: Well I'd like to know. I'll reboot in archlinux and print an exact log of what happens.

Comment: No, I mean if it *builds* correctly not install correctly.  AUR packages are built with `makepkg` but installed with `pacman -U`.  It is a two phase process.

Comment: Oh I suddently got it to work. I assumed it was either makepkg or pacman, not both. I didn't know the package was sources, for some reason I assumed it to be binaries. So yeah, it compiled and now I got it working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so to not leave the question in unanswered state.  As we concluded in the comments:

---

#### AUR packages are installed in 2 phases

This is intended by arch developers since anyone can submit an AUR package.  When you download an AUR packages you should *always* check the `PKGBUILD` files for malicious code.  Although AUR packages are verified by [Trusted Users](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_Trusted_User_Guidelines) there are just too many of them.  Moreover, I use arch for years and never saw malicious code in the installation script of any AUR package I use, nut some people [argue that they have](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/4k43yn/have_you_ever_found_anything_malicious_in_a_aur/).

When you build your package with `makeprg` you need to fulfill all dependencies for the build to succeed.  Several AUR packages contain source files that are compiled, some download the sources during the build process, others even download binary blobs (e.g. graphic card drivers).  Therefore dependencies are often header files and libraries that must be there when the build runs.

`makeprg` produces a file `<package>-<version>-<architecture>.pkg.tar.xz` which then needs to be fed to `pacman -U` to be installed.  This is also intended since then you do not need `root` permissions to run `makepkg`.

If you have `sudo` installed you can use `makepkg -i` to install the package once the build is complete.  This is safe, since only `pacman` will be called with `root` permissions.

#### mdm

The procedure above specifically for the `mdm-display-manager` would look as follows:

```
$ wget https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/mdm-display-manager.tar.gz
$ tar xzf mdm-display-manager.tar.gz
$ cd mdm-display-manager
$ makepkg
```

This will result in a file called `mdm-display-manager-2.0.10-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz` (or `i686` if you're on that architecture), which you need to feed to `pacman` as `root`:

```
# pacman -U /path/to/package/mdm-display-manager-2.0.10-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

Comment: Not only you don't need root permissions, but you actually are required to not be root. Which I find pretty dumb myself, but it's just a matter of taste. Also I don't see how you could detect malicious code just by glaring at it, the chances that anyone would actually be able to do that are close to 0%, so if there's malicious code you're going to install it, root or not.